# Executing arbitrary sls file with salt

Tags: saltstack

I'm learning about salt.

I understand that the way things work, state files must be put under a root directory specified statically in the master/minion config.

So my question is, is there a way to execute an arbitrary sls file on the filesystem, i.e. not under the configured file roots?

The purpose of this, is that I want my projects to include sls files describing the required state of the system on which they will be deployed, and ideally I'd like not to have to copy/symlink those files into the salt file root.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, salt looks for state files in [`file_roots`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/master.html#file-roots). You tell it which sls to execute by giving it a dot separated name, e.g. `salt '*' state.apply my.state` which salt will look for in `/srv/salt/my/state.sls` or `/srv/salt/my/state/init.sls` by default.

The files need to be present on the salt master (unless you are using minion in [masterless](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/quickstart.html) mode).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can kinda do what I want a few ways:
1. using the [`state.template`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html#salt.modules.state.template) function, I can specify the path to a sls template file to execute
2. In masterless mode, using [`salt-call` with `--file-root` and `--pillar-root`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/cli/salt-call.html#cmdoption-salt-call--file-root) arguments, I can set the file root and pillar root to any directory(but then it has to follow the file/pillar root directory structure, and have a top.sls file, unless I use `state.sls`).